# Sending json as Gzip in https in xamarin.forms for android

Tags: json, http, https, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am sending an rest API request to my server in HTTPS, and gets a json response, in my xamarin.forms android (OS is marshmallow).

Is the json response automatically compressed from the server to my client, or do i need to define something in my HttpClient class, in the android, in order for it to be compressed (i have bad internet so the compression is important to me...)

Answer (score 5):

**Decompression:**

In order to consume compressed JSON using `HttpClient` in Xamarin.Forms you have to create a `HttpClientHandler` this way:

```
var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};
httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
```

Alternatively you can use [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient) which supports decompression out of the box according to this [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27174/does-modernhttpclient-automatically-decompress-gzip-streams).

**Compression:**

To enable compression in Xamarin.Forms you need to compress the request content yourself. For this let's extend `HttpContent`:

```
public class JsonContent : HttpContent
    {
        private JsonSerializer serializer { get; }
        private object value { get; }

        public JsonContent(object value)
        {
            this.serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            this.value = value;
            Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");
        }

        protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
        {
            length = -1;
            return false;
        }

        protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var gzip = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(gzip))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Now we can wrap our content with `JsonContent` and it will be sent compressed to our backend:

```
var jsonContent = new JsonContent(new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" });
await httpClient.PostAsync(url, jsonContent));
```

**Backend:**

From your question I also understand that you are not sure if your 'server' is compressing the response. It should be very easy to check, check if your response contains `Content-Encoding: gzip` header.

P.S.: I created a sample project on [github](https://github.com/yuv4ik/Xamarin-Forms-HttpGzipPlayground) that contains a .NET Core MVC backend with GZip compression / decompression support and Xamarin.Forms iOS frontend which consumes and sends compressed data (using GZip) with both HttpClient and ModernHttpClient.
 
Screens attached:

[image]
[image]

Comment: if i do:                 
handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

is that enough for the data to be sent compressed from the server ? I see in the response the Content-Encoding: gzip, and the response is receiving unzipped in response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result

Comment: I guess you can try it and tell us if it did work. Check if the client's request contains 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'. Link to github project is also attached in my answer so you can play with it to understand the problem better.

Comment: @asaf yes it is enough. if you put fiddler in between you can see that response it encoded with gzip

Comment: @EvZ does xamarin use modernhttp client by default? is it only for android also valid for ios and uwp?